# ディスカッションの発生を避けるための注記

Tags: 討議

[phpでmysqlにデータを保存しているデータをid毎に静的フアィルhtmlに生成して書き出したいです](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/23525/php%E3%81%A7mysql%E3%81%AB%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%92%E4%BF%9D%E5%AD%98%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%92id%E6%AF%8E%E3%81%AB%E9%9D%99%E7%9A%84%E3%83%95%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A3%E3%83%ABhtml%E3%81%AB%E7%94%9F%E6%88%90%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E5%87%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99)

この質問は、コメントと回答を駆使してディスカッションが行われた結果、第三者には全く話が追えない(=Q&Aリソースとしては無価値な)状態となっています。

これは極端な例としても、コメントや回答でディスカッションが行われる例は多数あります。

現状でも、コメントの入力欄に「コメントを使って情報の追加を求めたり改善方法を提案したりします。コメントを使って回答しないでください」と説明がありますが、

- 指摘に対しては質問や回答を編集することで応えるようにしコメントで返信すべきではないことは伝わらない
- 字が薄い上1文字でも入力した瞬間消えてしまうのでそもそも気がつかれていない

と、あまり注意書きとしては機能していないようですので、はっきりとした注記を追加した方がいいように思います。

---

これを読んで「ディスカッションは一律に許されないのだ」と誤解される方がいるかも知れないので追記。

ディスカッションがまずいのは、「質問」と「回答」だけを見ても話が通じずコメントのやりとりをすべて追わないと質問の真意や正確な回答がわからない、という事態が引き起こされることです。「質問」と「回答」だけを取り出してもQ&Aとして成立する、という状態が理想ではないでしょうか。

従って、「質問への追加情報の依頼」→「依頼への疑義」→「依頼の訂正」とか、「回答への疑義」→「疑義への疑問の呈示」→「当初の疑義への補足」みたいなやりとりがコメント欄で行われるのは問題では無いと思います。「依頼への疑義」とか「疑義への疑問の呈示」のような内容を質問や回答に追記してもかえってわかりにくくなるだけでしょう。長くなるようならチャットにした方がよいですが。

回答欄は回答欄なのですからそこに質問を書くべきでないのは言うまでもないでしょう

上記追記部分については、この投稿を理由にして「ディスカッション(ユーザー同士のやりとり)は絶対に駄目だ」とされないよう、ヘルプセンターの記述や過去のメタの議論からおそらくこうであろうというSOのポリシーを書いたもので、この点について討議を求めているわけではありません。この点について討議が必要とお考えの場合は、新たに質問として投稿されれば良いと思います。

Comment: 異なるトピックを1つのスレの中に混在するのはよろしくない、と言うのはメタの方にも成り立つのでは無いでしょうか。追記部分の内容は「ディスカッションの発生を避けるための注記」と言う本題を随分離れているように思われます。「議論の余地があります」とされた部分以外にも議論の余地があるように思われますし、追記部分は別スレにしてもっと多くの方の意見を聞かれた方が良いのではないですか。

Comment: 新規ユーザーに表示される[回答時のガイド](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86576/286934)や [コメントの整形ガイド](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/inline-comment-and-post-markdown-help/)のように、信用度が一定以下のユーザーに対して表示する想定でしょうか。

Comment: @unarist ガイドですが、コメントの方は「ヘルプ」を押すと出てくる内容が最初から表示されてるのでしょうか。あと、現状の閾値はわかりますか？

Comment: 確かそうだったと思います。閾値は回答ガイドと同じく100点だと思います。（どこかのサイトで200点を満たせば他のサイトでも100点もらえる、という仕様と一致しますし）

Answer (score 3):

案です。テキストボックスの上に表示されることを想定しています。

### 質問のコメント欄

- コメントで求められた追加情報の要求や改善の提案にはコメントで返信せず質問の編集で行ってください
- コメントで質問に回答しないでください

### 回答の入力欄

- 追加の質問や「ありがとう」を回答として投稿しないでください
- 質問に対する追加情報の要求や改善の提案は質問のコメントを使って投稿してください

### 回答のコメント欄

- 回答内容の疑問点の確認はよいですが、追加の質問の場合は、元の質問を編集して行うか新たに別の質問として投稿してください
- 回答の訂正や追加情報はコメントではなく回答を編集して行ってください